# How to use svg sprite in Nextjs (Using use tag )

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, icons

I am cuurently working on a nextjs project, downloaded svg sprites and also configured nextjs with svgr/webpack , while using Normal as areact component the icons are been displayed, but i want to use it using svg sprite using use tag following are the code

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from "./Navbar.module.scss"
import logo from "../../../public/images/logo.png"
import Upload from "../../../public/icons/upload.svg";
import ChevronDown from "../../../public/icons/chevron-down.svg"
import Icons from "../../../public/icons/symbol-defs.svg"
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className={styles.navbar}>
            <div className={styles.navbar__left}>
                <div className={styles.navbar__logoContainer}>
                    <Image src={logo} alt="logo" className={styles.navbar__logo} objectFit='cover' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.navbar__right}>
                <Link href="/">
                    <a className={styles.explore__text}>
                        Explore
                        <svg className="explore__icon">
                            <use xlinkHref={`${Icons}#icon-chevron-down`}></use>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/">
                    <a className={styles.btn__text}>
                        Sign In
                    </a>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/">
                    <a className={styles.btn__text}>
                        Sign Up
                    </a>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/">
                    <a className={styles.btn__text}>
                        Upload
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </div>

        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

After using sprites the icons are not displayed but i am also not getting any error

Comment: Linkl to navigate from one page to another using Link given by nextjs to route another page without browser refresh

Comment: Try replacing the `use` tag with `<use href="/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-chevron-down"></use>`. Use the direct path inside the `public` folder, don't use the imported file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the use tag with `<use href="/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-chevron-down"></use>`. Use the direct path inside the `public` folder, don't use the imported file

credits - comment from [juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves)